# PHP integer-like strings

Tags: php, string, warnings

when i am using string to access array index, editor show warning.

> As of PHP 5.4 string offsets have to either be integers or
>   integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown.

can any body please explain the "integer-like strings" ? or reason for showing warning.

Additionally if same is use for $_POST it didn't show any warning.

Below snippet gives warning.

```
$POST = $_POST;
$POST['username']
```

While below didn't

```
$_POST['username']
```

Comment: the line you've quoted from the documentation is specific to strings, not arrays. everything is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-54).

Answer (score -1):

I would call integer-like strings everything php can convert to an integer, basically everything.

Which editor are you using? This warning is nonsense, php has the ability to use integers or strings as array index, thus you basically can dump everthing into the index of the array (Probably not an object).

```
$ar = array();
$ar['a string'] = 'Content';
$ar['11string'] = 'More Content';
$ar['1'] = 'More content';
$ar[1] = 'Even more';
```

All of these things are allowed.

**EDIT:**

As ShiraNai7 pointed out, the error is about accessing strings via the array modifier, in this case you are only allowed to use integers (or as said integer-like strings). This is primary the case, because you are accessing the `n`-th character of an string.

Still, there is no reason to show this warning at this point. Maybe you have some more complex code at this point, override `$POST` to a string?

Comment: Those are array keys. The warning is about *string offsets*: https://3v4l.org/m5RLZ

Comment: But this is not what the example is about. So I still hold my conclusion, that the error is nonsense at this point.

Comment: I am using phpstorm 2017.1.4